# How to detect when move_base is executing recovery behaviors

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

My problem is the following. When a robot is stuck and `move_base` is not able to find a valid plan I can see on `rqt_console` the corresponding ERROR and WARN messages:

[image: image description]

In this case, there's no path to the goal and `move_base` starts its recovery behaviors.

My question is: if I want to write a simple subscriber that is able to detect this situation (e.g. so that it can warn somehow the user) to which topic should I listen and how can I intercept this message?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343014/how-to-detect-when-move_base-is-executing-recovery-behaviors/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2020-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the page about [rqt_console](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_console) has the answer to this "rqt_console is a viewer in the rqt package that displays messages being published to rosout". You would also be able to see this in rqt_graph by deselecting the hide debug box so that nodes that are providing information about the system are visible (nodes considered debug are hidden by default as they involved in introspecting the system, rather than directly contributing to the robots behaviour, so are usually a distraction to what you are trying to see in the graph).

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2020-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can subscribe to  `/move_base/recovery_status` topic

---

Originally posted by [Ahmed Osman](https://answers.ros.org/users/36991/ahmed-osman/) with karma: 56 on 2021-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/33525/lsw/) on 2021-09-09**:
When I subscribe teh topic, I meet the error:
error: ‘RecoveryStatus’ in namespace ‘move_base_msgs’ does not name a type
7 | void RecoveryCallback(const move_base_msgs::RecoveryStatus msg){
and below as my code :
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include 
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <move_base_msgs/MoveBaseActionGoal.h>

void RecoveryCallback(const move_base_msgs::RecoveryStatus msg){

}
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "cmdveltest");
ros::NodeHandle nh;
ros::Subscriber sub_recovery = nh.subscribe("/move_base/recovery_status", RecoveryCallback);
ros::spin();
return 0;
}